# How to take a line input in C?

Tags: c, file-io, stdin, scanf

I was trying to take a full line input in C. Initially I did,

```
char line[100] // assume no line is longer than 100 letters.
scanf("%s", line);
```

Ignoring security flaws and buffer overflows, I knew this could never take more than a word input. I modified it again,

```
scanf("[^\n]", line);
```

This, of course, couldn't take more than a line of input. The following code, however was running into infinite loop,

```
while(fscanf(stdin, "%[^\n]", line) != EOF)
{
    printf("%s\n", line);
}
```

This was because, the `\n` was never consumed, and would repeatedly stop at the same point and had the same value in `line`. So I rewrote the code as,

```
while(fscanf(stdin, "%[^\n]\n", line) != EOF)
{
    printf("%s\n", line);
}
```

This code ***worked*** impeccably(or so I thought), for input from a file. But for input from `stdin`, this produced cryptic, weird, inarticulate behavior. Only after second line was input, the first line would print. I'm unable to understand what is really happening.

All I am doing is this. Note down the string until you encounter a `\n`, store it in `line` and then consume the `\n` from the input buffer. Now print this `line` and get ready for next line from the input. Or am I being misled?

At the time of posting this question however, I found a better alternative,

```
while(fscanf(stdin, "%[^\n]%*c", line) != EOF)
{
    printf("%s\n", line);
}
```

This works flawlessly for all cases. But my question still remains. How come this code,

```
while(fscanf(stdin, "%[^\n]\n", line) != EOF)
{
    printf("%s\n", line);
}
```

worked for inputs from file, but is causing issues for input from standard input?

Comment: Use fgets(), not fscanf().

Comment: I could very certainly do so. But that's like running away from the problem. This is to understand the behavior of `scanf`

Comment: I'll go for `fgets` too - don't forget it retains any trailing `newline`. As for `scanf` family, always check the correct *number of items converted*. `0` items converted will not be detected by `EOF` test, but `EOF` will be if the correct number of items were not converted.

Comment: Don't climb the mountain, go round it. `scanf` family is horrible when it stalls. Better to read the line with `fgets` and *then* use `sscanf`.

Comment: Very difficult to use scanf properly when you want a whole line - your regex still runs the risk of buffer overflow; you'll never have that problem with gets/fgets.

Comment: Sure I got it working properly with `fgets`. But that's not the question of **feasibility**, or of **security**. I got the right way with `scanf`(look at the code snippet in the question). I just want to understand why my code is showing unexpected behavior.

Comment: Your snippets are still testing for `EOF` returned. That will simply stall at any bad input. If you are reading a file and you don't get the right data, you might just as well throw in the towel - GIGO - but testing for `EOF` will cause a stall. The bad data stays there waiting to be read or removed somehow, but it is not the end of the file. `while(scanf("...", ...) == numberofitems) {...}`

Comment: @Djack To best diagnose, provide the code, its inputs, outputs and expected output that caused the "issues for input from standard input".

Comment: @FredK, Never use `gets()`   1) it will allow a input buffer overflow, 2) it is no longer a part of the C language  -- modern compilers will warn you to not use `gets()`

Comment: you might want to look at the functions `getline()` and `readline()`  for inputting a line at a time,

Comment: regarding this line: `while(fscanf(stdin, "%[^\n]%*c", line) != EOF)`   This will not properly handle multi character end-of-line sequences.  (Windows comes to mind) because it will have already read in the first char into the input buffer of `\r`, which you probably do not want

Answer (score 3):

Use `fgets()`. [@FredK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38576690/how-to-take-a-line-input-in-c#comment64542703_38576690)

```
char buf[N];
while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
  // crop potential \n if desired.
  buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0'; 
  ...
}
```

There are to many issues trying to use `scanf()` for user input that render it prone to mis-use or code attacks.

```
// Leaves trailing \n in stdin
scanf("%[^\n]", line)

// Does nothing if line begins with \n. \n remains in stdin
// As return value not checked, use of line may be UB.
// If some text read, consumes \n and then all following whitespace: ' ' \n \t etc.
//    Then does not return until a non-white-space is entered.
//    As stdin is usually buffered, this implies 2 lines of user input.
// Fails to limit input.
scanf("%[^\n]\n", line)

// Does nothing if line begins with \n. \n remains in stdin
// Consumes 1 char after `line`, even if next character is not a \n
scanf("%99[^\n]%*c", line)
```

Check against EOF is usual the *wrong* check.  [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38576690/how-to-take-a-line-input-in-c#comment64543423_38576690) The following, when \n is *first* entered, returns 0 as `line` is not populated.  As `0 != EOF`, code goes on to use an uninitialized `line` leading to UB.

```
while(fscanf(stdin, "%[^\n]%*c", line) != EOF)
```

Consider entering "1234\n" to the following. Likely infinite loop as first `fscanf()` read "123", tosses the "4" and the next `fscanf()` call gets stuck on \n.

```
while(fscanf(stdin, "%3[^\n]%*c", line) != EOF)
```

When checking the results of `*scanf()`, **check against what you want**, not against one of the values you do not want.  (But even the following has other troubles)

```
while(fscanf(stdin, "%[^\n]%*c", line) == 1)
```

---

About the closest `scanf()` to read a *line*:

```
char buf[100];
buf[0] = 0;
int cnt = scanf("%99[^\n]", buf);
if (cnt == EOF) Handle_EndOfFile();
// Consume \n if next stdin char is a \n
scanf("%*1[\n]");
// Use buf;
```

---

> `while(fscanf(stdin, "%[^\n]%*c", line) != EOF)`
>   worked for inputs from file, but is causing issues for input from standard input?

Posting sample code and input/data file would be useful.  With modest amount of code posted, some potential reasons.

`line` overrun is UB
Input begins with `\n` leading to UB
File or `stdin` not both opened in same mode. `\r` not translated in one.

---

Note: The following fails when a line is 100 characters.  So meeting the assumption cal still lead to UB.

```
char line[100] // assume no line is longer than 100 letters.
scanf("%s", line);
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think `fgets()` is badly designed. When I read a line, I want to read it in whole regardless of its length (except filling up all RAM). `fgets()` can't do that in one go. If there is a long line, you have to manually run it multiple times until it reaches the newline. The glibc-specific [getline()](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html) is more convenient in this regard. Here is a function that mimics GNU's getline():

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

long my_getline(char **buf, long *m_buf, FILE *fp)
{
    long tot = 0, max = 0;
    char *p;
    if (*m_buf == 0) { // empty buffer; allocate
        *m_buf = 16;   // initial size; could be larger
        *buf = (char*)malloc(*m_buf); // FIXME: check NULL
    }
    for (p = *buf, max = *m_buf;;) {
        long l, old_m;
        if (fgets(p, max, fp) == NULL)
            return tot? tot : EOF; // reach end-of-file
        for (l = 0; l < max; ++l)
            if (p[l] == '\n') break;
        if (l < max) { // a complete line
            tot += l, p[l] = 0;
            break;
        }
        old_m = *m_buf;
        *m_buf <<= 1; // incomplete line; double the buffer
        *buf = (char*)realloc(*buf, *m_buf); // check NULL
        max = (*m_buf) - old_m;
        p = (*buf) + old_m - 1; // point to the end of partial line
    }
    return tot;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    long l, m_buf = 0;
    char *buf = 0;
    while ((l = my_getline(&buf, &m_buf, stdin)) != EOF)
        puts(buf);
    free(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

I usually use my own readline() function. I wrote this `my_getline()` a moment ago. It has not been thoroughly tested. Please use with caution.

Comment: Note that *nix uses `ssize_t getline (char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream)` uses `size_t*`, not `long *`.  Any particular reason for this code's change?  BTW: code has leak: Should `free(*buf)` before `*buf = malloc(*m_buf);`  `l = strlen(p);  if (p[l-1]...` is a hacker exploit as first character returned from `fgets()` may be a null character.

Comment: There is no leak. If `buf` is preallocated, `*m_buf` should be positive. Then you never run into `malloc`. As to `size_t` etc, feel free to change. The above just shows a sketch. For a proper library function, we need to at least check `*alloc()`. The first char `fgets()` returns should not be a NULL (oh, wait, unless `*m_buf` equals 1).

Comment: `*buf` may be non-`NULL` and `*m_buf` may be 0.  `long m_buf = 0; char *buf = malloc(m_buf); my_getline(&buf, &m_buf, stdin);`  IAC, it is a corner case. just a FYI

Comment: No, that is misuse of the function. If `m_buf=0` but `buf` is uninitialized, you will end up with a segfault. There is no effective way to protect against all kinds of misuses.

Comment: "first char fgets() returns should not be a NULL" Why not? Hacker types in the key sequence for the null character, then <enter>.  This leads to `"\0\n\0"` and breaks this code.

Comment: Disagree about misuse.  With `long m_buf = 0; char *buf = malloc(m_buf); my_getline(&buf, &m_buf, stdin);`, both `buf` and `m_buf` are initialized.

Comment: That is a misuse. The result of the misuse is that you have a memory leak. That is caller's problem. Caller can easily trigger a segfault, too.

Comment: You are right on the `\0\n\0` part. I have fixed the code.